# MS Access IIF using IN condition

Tags: sql, ms-access

Im trying to add a field into a table that indicates whether the value exists in another table. Heres what I have

```
table1:     table2:
id          id  
1           2
2           4
3           6
```

End result:

```
table3:
id   inTable2
1    no
2    yes
3    no
```

Heres what I have so far.

```
SELECT id, IIf(id In (SELECT id FROM table2 GROUP BY id), "yes", "no") AS inTable2 INTO table3
```

I'm getting error "An action query cannot be used by a rowsource".
Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Where are you using that expression? A calculated field?

Comment: i think so? Im using it like SELECT id, iif(..) AS inTable2

Comment: That sounds like a query. If so, share the full query, I might be able to optimize it using an `INNER JOIN` instead.

Comment: updated, I tried using the inner join but I couldn't figure out how to create the "inTable2" field from the INNER JOIN

Answer (score 1):

You are close.  The `group by` is unnecessary:

```
IIf(id In (SELECT id FROM table2), "yes", "no")
```

However, I'm not 100% sure this will fix your problem.  This will work in a `SELECT` query, but your error suggests a different type of query.

You can try putting an index on `table2(id)`.  However, I might write this as:

```
iif(exists (select 1 from table2 where table2.id = ?.id), "yes", "no")
```

This should take advantage of an index on `table2(id)`.

Comment: oh Im creating a table with the results, I forgot to put that part in. If the table2 has 10mil entries but only 10k unique ids, would the GROUP BY speed up the process?

Comment: i think the id IN (SELECT id FROM table2) is the problem. Ive never used a WHERE condition for an IIF condition before, is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

You can probably optimize this query by using a `LEFT JOIN` instead:

```
SELECT t1.id, IIF(t2.id IS NULL, "yes", "no") INTO table3
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
```

Comment: That works thank you. Out of curiosity, do you know if its possible to do with an IF statement?

Comment: JET/ACE SQL does not feature an `IF` statement, so that would be a no.

Comment: i mean like the way I was trying it before, with the iif(...)

Comment: Nope, you can't use a join in an iif. You could use a `DCount` or something like that, but that would be horribly slow compared to this way.

Comment: If this answered your question, you can show so by [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). That way, other readers know the question has been answered, and both you and I get a rep bonus.